# How to delete all "Values" in RStudio Environment?

Tags: r, rstudio, delete-file

I know that rm(list=ls()) can delete all objects in the current environment.

However, environment has three categories: Data, Values, Functions. I wonder how I can only delete all the objects in one particular category? Something like

```
rm(list=ls(type="Values"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626229/how-to-delete-all-values-in-rstudio-environment#new-answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `ls.str` to specify a `mode`, or `lsf.str` for functions. The functions have print methods that make it look otherwise, but underneath are just vectors of object names, so

```
rm(list = lsf.str())
```

will remove all user-defined functions, and

```
rm(list = ls.str(mode = 'numeric'))
```

will remove all numeric vectors (including matrices). `mode` doesn't correspond exactly to class, though, so there's no way to distinguish between lists and data.frames with this method.

Answer (score 6):

One option is that you can change the view to grid view and check all the boxes next to  the ones you want to delete and click the broom button.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I'm aware, Data, Values and Functions are terms used by the RStudio interface. Data = variables with dimensions *e.g.* data frames, matrices, Values = other variables (*e.g.* vectors). They are not terms that can be accessed via R code.